# Site upgrade to D7 using drush stuck on the "Run update.php" step

Tags: drush, upgrading

I am attempting upgrading my site from D6 to D7 using Drush Site upgrade.

The process gets stuck on the 13th step. This is the last output I get :

```
    UPGRADE.txt Major Upgrade Step 13

13. Run update.php by visiting http://www.example.com/update.php (replace
    www.example.com with your domain name). This will update the core database
    tables.

    If you are unable to access update.php do the following:

    - Open settings.php with a text editor.

    - Find the line that says: $update_free_access = FALSE;

    - Change it into: $update_free_access = TRUE;

    - Once the upgrade is done, $update_free_access must be reverted to FALSE.

Note that Drush will copy your database and run updatedb on the copy. The
source database remains unchanged.

Drush will automatically do this step now.
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of drush? site-upgrade started being a drush core command (in drush 4.x) but it was moved out in drush 5 and is now being worked at http://drupal.org/project/drush_sup

Comment: I am using Drush 5.4 with the latest alpha version of Drush Site Upgrade

Comment: This question has been moved to the drush site upgrade issue queue: http://drupal.org/node/1674878

Answer (score 2):

You may get the information you need by running drush with the verbose flag: -v or --verbose.